# return null in usage of full text search in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, full-text-search

My program has a database with 100.000 records when I want to search and filter simultaneously in my program with full text search in SQL server but in entity framework It dose not work. 
the name of library I used is"Fissoft.EntityFramework.Fts"

```
 var text = FullTextSearchModelUtil.FreeText("searched text", true);
            var query = db.Mainindustapp.Where(c => c.UnitName.Contains(text)).ToList();
            return query.ToList();
```

but when I send full text search code directly in to SQL server it will response. below code is what I said:

```
 Mainindustapp = db.Mainindustapp.SqlQuery
             ("SELECT * FROM[DB_industapp].[dbo].[Mainindustapps] WHERE FREETEXT(([UnitName], [Product]), @p0)", SearchString);
```

and I should mentioned that catalogs is enabled in SQL server.

Comment: You are only searching `UnitName` via Linq/EF but `UnitName` **OR** `Product` when querying via Sql. Did you already try `.Where(c => "*".Contains(text))` as suggested in the [demo](https://github.com/fissoft/Fissoft.EntityFramework.Fts/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: are you getting anything in `query` ?? and why are you returning `query.ToList()` you can omit the tolist part, just pass the query. It is already in list format

Answer (score 0):

To do this, please use this "Install-Package EfFts" library

please check site : https://effts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

You only search by a UnitName when you write this:

```
  var query = db.Mainindustapp.Where(c => c.UnitName.Contains(text)).ToList();
```

Try this and I think it will work:

```
var query = db.Mainindustapp.Where(c =>"*".Contains(text)).ToList();
```